# How to use an inline Web Worker without an external file with Ember?

Tags: ember.js, web-worker

From reading [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp) and the [Web Worker tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/). I attempted to create an Ember app that calls a web worker to post a message in the console every second. However, something is not working. You can see it in action [in this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/iwiruw/465/edit).

```
if(typeof(Worker)!=="undefined") {

    var blob = new Blob(["setInterval(function(){console.log('Hello');},1000);"]);

    // Obtain a blob URL reference to our worker 'file'.
    var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

    var worker = new Worker(blobURL);
    worker.onmessage = function(e) {
        console.log('inside onmessage');
        // e.data == 'msg from worker'
    };
    worker.postMessage(); // Start the worker.    
}
else
{
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support Web Workers...";
}
```

Comment: FYI, W3Schools has nothing to do with the W3C. See http://www.w3fools.com/